# Value of infinite product

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let A be a set of n elements.The number of ways we can choose and ordered pair (B,C) where B,C are disjoint subsets of A equals:

A) $n^2$ B)$n^3$ C)$2^n$ D) $3^n$

Here my answer is coming to D) $3^n$ because every single element has 3 possibilities of going either to B or C or none of B or C

But Lets check my answer with A containing 3 elements A={1,2,3} The disjoint subsets can be 
a) B={1}, C={2} and vice versa

b) B={1}, C={3} and vice versa

c) B={2}, C={3} and vice versa

So there are 6 possibilities of ordered pair (B,C).
Now coming to 2 & 1 possibilities

d) B={1,2} C={3} and vice versa

e) B={1,3} C={2} and vice versa

f) B={2,3} C={1} and vice versa

So there are 6 possibilities of ordered pair (B,C).
Finally 3 & 0 possibilities

g) B={1,2,3} C= null set and vice versa

So there are two possibilities.

Total there are 6+6+2+1(B=null,C=null) = 15 possibilities

But from my answer it should come to $3^3$= 27 possibilities

Where am I going wrong? Please help

Comment: What about $1\& 0$ cases, or $2\& 0$ or, for that matter, $0 \& 0$?

Comment: Ah, I see you slipped $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ in via parenthetic note.  But you are still missing things like $(\{1\},\emptyset)$ or $(\emptyset,\{2,3\})$.

Comment: @lulu yes you are right I missed those things...If those sets are taken into account it will be 27 combinations...Thank you...:)

Comment: But are null sets null set not joint sets?

Comment: Of course they are disjoint.  I just hadn't seen that you included that case.

Comment: Please change that irrelevant title.

Answer (score 1):

$\{1,2,3\}$ has $8$ subsets:

$$
\{\},\\
\{1\},\\
\{1,2\},\\
\{2\},\\
\{1,3\},\\
\{2,3\},\\
\{1,2,3\},\\
\{3\},
$$
of sizes $0,1,2,1,2,2,3,1$.

Then number of disjoint subsets are respectively

$$8,4,2,4,2,2,1,4$$ (i.e. $2^{3-\#S_i}$) the sum of which $27$.

---

More generally, the number of subsets of size $k$ are $\displaystyle\binom nk$, leading to the total number of subset combinations

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk 2^k=(2+1)^n.$$